# Put two ajax helpers text boxes next to eachother

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I put 2 input text boxes next to each other that share the same search button with AJAX forums?  When I try to do it it ignores the second text box input.

One input is searching an event by Event Name or Type and the second input is for searching an event by location.

Here is my code for my view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<h2>Home</h2>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Event Search</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EventSearch", "Events", new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            OnFailure = "searchFailed",
            LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
            UpdateTargetId = "searchresults"

        }))
        {
            <input type="text" name="q" /> <input type="submit" value="search" />


        }

        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("LocationSearch", "Events", new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            OnFailure = "searchFailed",
            LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
            UpdateTargetId = "searchresults"

        }))
        {

            <input type="text" name="e" /> <input type="submit" value="search" />

        }

        <div id="searchresults"></div>
    </div>


</div>

@section Scripts{

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/App/EventSearch.js"></script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single form instead of two separate forms to achieve the same.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Events", new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        OnFailure = "searchFailed",
        LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
        UpdateTargetId = "searchresults"

    }))
    {
        <input type="text" name="q" /> 
        <input type="text" name="e" />
        <input type="submit" value="search" />
    }
```

Now you can make a single controller action to handle both types of requests.

For instance

```
public ActionResult Search(string e,string q)
{
     //Here you can differentiate
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e))
     {
         //Search by Event
     }
     else
     {
         //Search by Type
     }
     return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you, to create a **single form** (with both input fields and single button) instead of two forms.

Create **one model** for search with properties as **EventName, Location**.

Make a **single POST request**(Action Method) and POST that **model** to server.

And distinguish your search filter at the server by properties in your model.